Masked Gitlab CI Variables
I am trying to use a masked CI variable in a downstream script and it does not appear to work "as advertised" - I haven't found any clarifying information on usage to help.
Basically, a very complicated CI pipeline should pass a protected and masked variable down to a python script that actually uses it. This is not working. The python script use os.environ.get() to grab the CI variable. It "succeeds" but the value comes out as [Masked].
Now this is "sort of" expected in that the whole point is to obfuscate the value in human readable forms such as a pipeline job log (echo or print()). The problem is that the actual value it grabs is literally just "[Masked]" as in the masking gets interpreted as the actual variable value.
I was expecting that the actual value would be correct, but the Gitlab CI pipeline would replace it with [Masked] whenever it was "exposed". That is the variable value would be correct but if you tried to print or echo then, and only then, would it be [Masked].
For example:
MY_CI_VARIABLE = 23 # Masked variable. 

myVariable = os.environ.get('MY_CI_VARIABLE') # the value of myVariable should be 23 
print(myVariable) # This should show up a [Masked]

myNewVariable = myVariable + 1 # this should be 24 because myVariable should be usable by the script

print(myNewVariable) # this should show 24

This does NOT work.
My one thought is that this is not the correct way to access the variable in python and that I need to use the Gitlab CLI in python with a Job token to actually pull the masked variable correctly.
However, there is another odd behavior that seems like it is masking the variable value in ALL instances, not just the variable itself.
Example:
MY_CI_VARIABLE = "PRODUCTION_BOTH"

Then in python I just have a print statement such as
print('Now using the "PRODUCTION_BOTH" variable...')
This prints out
"Now using the [Masked] variable..."
This seems to contradict my statement above about incorrectly pulling the masked variable into python as it seems that masking occurs anytime the Masked variable value is used, regardless of how, when, or why. Meaning that on the positive side, the Masking is working in the downstream python script because I get errors when I try to use the variable as "[Masked]" is not a valid value for the application it is being used in.

I don't see how print('Now using the "PRODUCTION_BOTH" variable...') could possibly print Now using the [Masked] variable..., because PRODUCTION_BOTH is a literal string, not any kind of variable.

myNewVariable = myVariable + 1 Also this would not work, because myVariable is a string, and you can't add an integer to string.  It's very confusing when you present code and say "this should work", when it clearly cannot.

@JohnGordon Sorry, maybe it was the brevity in which I set on the examples, but myVariable is pulling the value of MY_CI_VARIABLE from example 1 which is a integer value 23 in that example.
As for your first comment, yea, I agree. Hence why I am confused that the value is Masked even when not part of the actual masked variable. It is super confusing and one of the motivations for asking this question.

What you're looking for seems to be gitlab secrets:

Secrets management is the systems that developers use to securely store sensitive data in a secure environment with strict access controls. A secret is a sensitive credential that should be kept confidential. Examples of a secret include:

Passwords
SSH keys
Access tokens
Any other types of credentials where exposure would be harmful to an organization


They are specifically required by a job and are not viewable by every person who has access to the job's log. You might want to also take a look at pipeline security

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
